# ios - Swift JSON Post request

Tags: ios, json, swift, post

I'm new in swift language.This is my JSON which needs to be send to server for user login

```
data={"email":"test@***.com","password":"mypassword","service":"login","deviceid":"sasa","devicetype":"android"}
```

I tried these codes

```
    let params = [
            "data": [
                "email": username,
                "password": password,
                "service": "login",
                "deviceid": "sasa",
                "devicetype": "android"
            ]
        ]
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://***.com/login", parameters: params, encoding: .JSON)
            .responseJSON {  response in
                print(response)
                        }
```

but the response from server

```
SUCCESS: {
    service = login;
    status = failure;
    statusmessage = "Failure in post request , please check the key for form data";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use encoding type URL instead of JSON:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://***.com/login", parameters: params, encoding: .URL)
            .responseJSON {  response in
                print(response)
                        }
```